# Is it possible to get the array base, not just the view, from PyBind11?

Tags: python, c++, numpy, buffer, pybind11

Numpy arrays in Python are of two kinds: base arrays and views.

However, I cannot see a way to distinguish the two kinds of arrays from the buffer protocol, and I cannot see a way in C++ to obtain the base array from a view.

Is it possible to determine the base array in PyBind11 using the Buffer protocol, or from a Python Object?

I need this so I can write the whole memory buffer associated with an array to disk so I can properly reconstruct it later.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy already has facilities for saving arrays: [`np.save`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) and [`np.load`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.load.html). You can even have a mmap'ed array with [`np.memmap`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html).

If you still want to implement this yourself, pybind11's buffer wrapper can generate a `py::buffer_info` object that will have the information about where and how the buffer's data is stored in memory.

As [documented here](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/pycpp/numpy.html#buffer-protocol), the `buffer_info` struct looks like this:

```cpp
struct buffer_info {
    void *ptr;
    py::ssize_t itemsize;
    std::string format;
    py::ssize_t ndim;
    std::vector<py::ssize_t> shape;
    std::vector<py::ssize_t> strides;
};
```

And you may access it like this:

```cpp
void f(py::buffer my_buffer) {
  py::buffer_info my_buffer_info = my_buffer.request();
  do_something(my_buffer_info.ptr);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I do already use the buffer_info structure to get at the array view.  However, I believe that structure does not contain any information about the array base. The reason I want access to the base is so that multiple views on the same array can be stored only a single time.